# Is `fun x -> x` the only function that has type 'a -> 'a in OCaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

The title is the question, simple.

The identity function `fun x -> x` has the type `'a -> 'a`.

**Are there any other functions with the same type `'a -> 'a`?**

I can't think of another.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No.

```
fun x -> print_endline "foo"; x;;

(failwith "bang" : 'a -> 'a);;

(fun x -> failwith "bang" : 'a -> 'a);;

(fun x -> List.hd [] : 'a -> 'a);;

let rec f (x : 'a) : 'a = f x;;

let counter = ref 0;;
(fun x -> incr counter; x);;
```

The identity function is the only inhabitant of `'a -> 'a` in total programming language with no side-effects whatsoever, including nontermination. Neither OCaml nor Haskell qualify, but some languages used as proof assistants (where this totality is important) do, in particular Coq (which has the impredicative polymorphism used to formulate this type).

Comment: Partial function application can give you any number of those too, right?  If you have 'b -> 'a -> 'a  and apply that to just 'b you get 'a -> 'a

Comment: @plinth: You'll have to [eta-expand](http://caml.inria.fr/resources/doc/faq/core.en.html#eta-expansion), but sure. However, I don't think it makes a difference: I mean you could always compute the result of the application yourself and you would  get a closed program expressible as `'a -> 'a` directly, similar to the ones I have given above.